# split a large csv file

Tags: linux, csv, manjaro

I have a `game_data.csv` file with over a million rows (70MB in size). I am writing an app that is going to do some processing on the CSV and write the CSV data into a database.

Whilst I'm developing the app, I would like a smaller CSV to work against, what Linux command can I run that will grab me the first 1500 rows of the CSV and put that into a separate CSV file `subset_game_data.csv`?

I am on Manjaro Linux (in case that matters).

Comment: If the data contains no newlines, this is trivially done with `head -n 1500`.

Comment: Thanks @Hermann I can't believe I didn't think of that, I blame the fact that I'm still fairly new to linux. I just ran `head -n 1500 game_data.csv >> subset_game_data.csv` and it worked! You can write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data contains no newlines, this is trivially done with `head -n 1500 game_data.csv > subset_game_data.csv`.

If the data *does* contain newlines, you need to parse it properly. Use any tool like Libreoffice Calc or a python script. [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can do the trick with something like

```
csvsql --query "select * from data limit 1500" game_data.csv > subset_game_data.csv
```